# How can I emulate TSQL's DateDiff correctly in C#

Tags: c#, t-sql, datetime

I seem to get different results when using the TimeSpan functionality in C# against TSQL DateDiff.  It seems that DateDiff gives the number of days between 2 dates regardless of the time-stamp, whereas in C# it takes into consideration the timestamp.  So if the 1st timestamp is at 10am, and the 2nd timestamp is at 9am the following day, the timespan is 0 days, whereas DateDiff will return 1.

```
declare @d1 datetime
declare @d2 datetime

set @d1 = '2/9/2011 10:00'
set @d2 = '2/10/2011 09:00'

select datediff(day, @d1, @d2)
-- prints 1
```

Using C# DateTime and DateTime span.

```
  // will return 1 with same dates
  private static int DateDiff(DateTime from, DateTime to)
  {
        return (new DateTime(from.Year, from.Month, from.Day)
                - new DateTime(to.Year, to.Month, to.Day)).Days;            
  }
```

Question is, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is because DATEDIFF returns the number of such boundaries crossed. [DATEDIFF (Transact SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your method shorter, like this:

```
private static int DateDiff(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    return (to.Date - from.Date).Days;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public enum DateInterval
    {
        Second, Minute, Hour, Day, Week, Month, Quarter, Year
    }

  public long DateDiff(DateInterval Interval, System.DateTime StartDate, System.DateTime EndDate)
    {
        long lngDateDiffValue = 0;
        System.TimeSpan TS = new System.TimeSpan(EndDate.Ticks - StartDate.Ticks);
        switch (Interval)
        {
            case DateInterval.Day:
                lngDateDiffValue = (long)TS.Days;
                break;
            case DateInterval.Hour:
                lngDateDiffValue = (long)TS.TotalHours;
                break;
            case DateInterval.Minute:
                lngDateDiffValue = (long)TS.TotalMinutes;
                break;
            case DateInterval.Month:
                lngDateDiffValue = (long)(TS.Days / 30);
                break;
            case DateInterval.Quarter:
                lngDateDiffValue = (long)((TS.Days / 30) / 3);
                break;
            case DateInterval.Second:
                lngDateDiffValue = (long)TS.TotalSeconds;
                break;
            case DateInterval.Week:
                lngDateDiffValue = (long)(TS.Days / 7);
                break;
            case DateInterval.Year:
                lngDateDiffValue = (long)(TS.Days / 365);
                break;
        }
        return (lngDateDiffValue);
    }//end of DateDiff
```

I found this method works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
private static int DateDiff(DateTime From, DateTime To)
{
    return From.Subtract(To).Days;            
}
```